# Creating S3 bucket policy in serverless - An error occurred: BucketPolicy - Invalid policy syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to add an S3 bucket policy in my serverless.yml file which would grant an IAM user I created permissions on the bucket.

I began by simply adding the policy on a bucket in a different stage (dev) directly in the console and now I am trying to replicate the policy in serverless on a different stage (test).

However, even though I am following the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html#aws-properties-s3-policy--examples) I can't quite seem to get it right. Here is a look at the policy in my serverless.yml file. To reduce potential for error I am copying my Principal and Resource directly.

```
    S3CredentialsBucket:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    BucketPolicy:
      Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
      Properties:
        Bucket: !Ref S3CredentialsBucket
        PolicyDocument:
          Id: ProdAnsiblePolicy
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            -
              Effect: Allow
              Principal: 'arn:aws:iam::***********:user/prodAnsible'
              Action: 's3:*'
              Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::test-mr-2-current-tenant-configurations'
```

Here is a look at the policy I added to the bucket directly in the console which works - meaning the user can put objects in the bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::***********:user/prodAnsible"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev-2-current-tenant-configurations"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::***********:user/prodAnsible"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev-2-current-tenant-configurations/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

As things are I get the following error when trying to deploy: `"An error occurred: BucketPolicy - Invalid policy syntax."`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Lastly here is a look at the serverless file cloudformation-template-update-stack.json.

```
    "S3TenantConfigBucket": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    },
    "BucketPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "Bucket": {
          "Ref": "S3TenantConfigBucket"
        },
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Id": "ProdAnsiblePolicy",
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::249161078948:user/prodAnsible"
              },
              "Action": "s3:*",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-mr-2-current-tenant-configurations/*"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It's also worth noting this is how the bucket is created:

```
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.s3_bucket}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

It's an event driven approach per the [serverless docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the principle you specify is an IAM user, you need to add this as the value of the `AWS` key. Ref: [AWS JSON Policy Elements: Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)

```
    S3CredentialsBucket:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    BucketPolicy:
      Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
      Properties:
        Bucket: !Ref S3CredentialsBucket
        PolicyDocument:
          Id: ProdAnsiblePolicy
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS: 'arn:aws:iam::***********:user/prodAnsible'
              Action: 's3:*'
              Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::test-mr-2-current-tenant-configurations'
```

Comment: This seems close! I am now getting " An error occurred: BucketPolicy - Policy has invalid resource" but according to docs this looks good https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html. And I am certain the bucket exist, Any more ideas?

Comment: @00robinette Could you update the `cloudformation-template-update-stack.json`? How does it look like now?

Comment: @00robinette Could you double check the IAM user `prodAnsible` and the S3 bucket `test-mr-2-current-tenant-configurations` exist?

Comment: They do, but I am wondering if this has to do with how I am referencing the bucket. It's created using the lambda event so I think "S3CredentialsBucket" doesn't reference it appropriately.